# How to consume Django Rest Framework with a simple python application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to make a python app to make a connection with the API

The python app is gonna send the user's ID to the API, then it's gonna get  some informations about this user, such as their name, whether they are authenticated and so on.

I already know how to create the rest api, But I don't know how to consume it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Use it like this:

```
# Get 
resp = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
json_response = resp.json()
# Response: {u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
is_authenticated = json_response.get('is_authenticated', False)
if is_authenticated == True:
   # Do stuff

# Post
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
r.json()
# Similar response as above
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you please show how to read the response and for example check some boolean information and then return the value.

Comment: Thanks again, But I still have one question. I didn't understand why You put false in the parentheses. I can't figure this out.

Comment: It means if json_response dictionary does not contain any parameter named `is_authenticated`, then it will return False as default value